# adding HTML5 audio source via javascript doesn't work only if external stylesheet is present

Tags: html5-audio

I am adding the audio source via javascript:

```
<audio id="audiotest" preload="none" controls volume=".2">
  <source type="audio/ogg">
  <source type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script>
var audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
var canPlayAudio = (audioTag.play)? true : false;
if(canPlayAudio) {
    var oggSource = document.getElementById("audiotest").children[0];
    var mp3Source = document.getElementById("audiotest").children[1];
    oggSource.src="test.ogg";
    mp3Source.src="test.mp3";
}
</script>
```

This fails in Chrome and Firefox if there is an external stylesheet.  Firefox compains about no src attribute. If I remove the `<link rel="stylesheet" src="whatever.css">` then it works.

I absolutely don't understand why.

Working test cases:
Fails (with external stylesheet): http://www.joshblackburn.com/test1.html
Works (no stylesheet): http://www.joshblackburn.com/test2.html

What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird one. I'm not sure why the stylesheet is causing issues, but in test1.html you can resolve the issue by adding the following line to the end of your script:

```js
document.getElementById("audiotest").load()
```

A better method might be to exclude the `audiotest` element all together from your HTML and simply add it using javascript:

```js
var audio = new Audio();
audio.id = 'audiotest';
audio.src = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? 'test.mp3' : 'test.ogg';
audio.volume = 0.2;
audio.preload = 'none';
audio.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```